# Whats the best way to setup an IIS7 Webfarm for an ASP.NET Application

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, load-balancing, high-availability, web-farm

We are looking to setup an IIS7 WebFarm... We have 2 IIS7/Windows Server 2008 boxes that will act as the load balanced webservers.

1. How do you setup IIS/Windows Server 2008 to handle balancing the requests between the 2 servers?
2. What is the best way to sync deployments so we only have to deploy to 1 place.  Can we just have them sync their structures or do we have to use a NAS/Network Share?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at Windows [Network Load Balancing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758834%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [Distributed File System](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732863%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: An alternative to DFS would be the msdeploy framework. http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/01/22/welcome-to-the-web-deployment-team-blog.aspx

Comment: +1 to both. I would use DFS - keeps everything in sync. NLB is the way to go.

Comment: Unless you have a file server or MSCS cluster, in which case configuring both nodes to access files on the file server via UNC path is the best way to go. Allows you to maintain a single code base and ensure that both webservers are dishing out the EXACT same content, not replicated copies of it.

As for load balancing, NLB is the way to go.

Comment: The issue with using a UNC path, in my opinion, is that if the server hosting that share has a problem it will bring ALL of the nodes down with it (single point of failure).  With DFS the files get stored on each machine locally and stay synchronized.  If the main file server goes down, the individual nodes are not directly impacted.